# How to access WriteResult in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following in my python file:

```
result = db.clients.update_one({'id':client['client']['id']},{'$set':{
    "name" : client['client']['name'],
}},True)
```

I want to retrieve how many records were inserted and how many were updated. I know I have to use WriteResults, but I can't seem to figure out how.

*this is one  a loop
*The update/insert works. I just don't know how to get the status of inserts vs updates

I am new to python and new to pymongo :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to access the values you want by

```
result.modified_count
```

and

```
result.upserted_id   #Will be None if no upsert took place
```

And don't forget that the built in `dir` method is a great tool to use when you want to see all the methods and properties available to you on a Python object.
Try this:

```
print dir(result)
```

**EDIT**
See documentation here:
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html?highlight=pymongo.results#pymongo.results.BulkWriteResult

Comment: Thank you. I finally found the documentation for UpdateResult. If anyone else needs it -> https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.1/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult

Comment: Good to hear, I went ahead and added it in the answer as well!

Comment: Just waiting for those 8 mins to pass ;)